# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'; for my specific code

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to take a filename and a list of column names and returns a list of integers that contains the values in those columns from every row (the order of the integers does not matter).

This is my current code:

```
def extract_data(filename, column_names):
    with open(filename) as election:
        elects = [row for row in csv.DictReader(election)]
    results = ([row[cn].replace(",", "")
                for cn in column_names] for row in elects)
    results = [row for row in results if '' not in row]
    return list((results))


def extract_election_votes(filename, column_names):
    results = extract_data(filename, column_names)
    **return [int(vote) for vote in results]**
```

For the line that is bolded (which the error is showing), how can I change it so that the error does not persist. Thanks.

[Data/Results CSV File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBQC6.png)

Comment: What does `results` look like?

Comment: updated in description

Comment: Is there any special reason to `return list((results))`? (Using two parentheses)

Comment: no there isn't. i removed the extra set of parentheses and still get the same error.

Comment: You could change `int(vote)` to `vote` and the error won't persist.

Comment: when i did that i got an error for my code: ```results = ([row[cn].replace(",", "") for cn in column_names] for row in elects)``` that said TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'